# Command prompt doesn't exit

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch file that - between an instruction and another - create some others batch files.

The new batch files are [imho] right, and everyone have this structure:

```
@ ECHO OFF
<application> <argument>
EXIT
```

For almost all of this batch files, `<application>` is a portable version of Chrome and `<argument>` is the site that I have to open, so I can open it from the `run` console simply writing its name [which call the batch file created].

Ok, here's my problem: when the browser isn't open yet, the `cmd.exe` windows that opens to execute the batch file won't close [Which does instead when the browser is already opened!]...

What I thought is the browser's task is linked to the console that opened it, but when I close the browser the command prompt still remains.

I tried also replacing:

```
<application> <argument>
EXIT
```

with:

```
<application> <argument> & EXIT
```

having the same issue.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try

```
@ECHO OFF
START "" <application> <argument>
CLS
EXIT
```

But I haven't tried it...

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work [=
Could you explain me why and where's the difference between calling a program by its path and using `START ""`?

Comment: start commences an independent process and continues (unless you use the `START /wait` option.) Executing an executable waits until the executable terminates before proceeding. see `start /?` from the prompt for info...